# Decrement in recursion. Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, decrement

```js
const factorial = (n) => {
  if (n === 0) return 1;
  return factorial(n - 1) * n;
};
console.log(factorial(5)); //Output: 120


const factorial = (n) => {
  if (n === 0) return 1;
  return factorial(--n) * n;
};
console.log(factorial(5)); //Output: 0
```

What the difference? Why in the second example i get 0.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? `--n` and `n--` is not the same

Comment: You multiply by zero at the very end.

Comment: `return factorial(--n) * n;` -> for `n == 1` -> `return factorial(--1) * 0;`

Comment: Try `return n * factorial(--n);`